# Can teamcity be made to build the latest tag in a git branch?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

I know that this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827063/get-teamcity-to-build-latest-tag) a year ago and there was a manual answer, but I was wondering if it would be possible to use something like `git describe` to get the latest tag and then use instead of the more manual approach that was given before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in "[How to get latest tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277828/6309)", using [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) can be enough to get the last tag:

```
git describe --abbrev=0         # shows only annotated tags.
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags  # includes lightweight (non-annotated) tags.
```

If TeamCity can call a first job which set a property used for the [Source Control parameters](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Git+%28JetBrains%29) of a second job, you could use that property with the latest tag as a value to build.